# Cannot render a variable containing " in React

Tags: reactjs, icons, escaping

I am trying to render the variable icon into the react component - see code below

```
render() {    

    const elementsRender = this.state.elements.map(elements => {
      // Formating variables
      const folderBorder = (elements.type === "folder") ? " folder-border" :"";


      const icon = "<i className="material-icons">folder </i>"


      const text =`<h1>A heading</h1>`
      console.log(icon)

      const addIcon = (elements.type === "folder") ? icon : "not a folder";


      return <li key={elements.index}>

        <div className={"infobox-parent"+ folderBorder}>
          <div className={elements.type +" "+elements.level}>

          {elements.type === "folder" ? icon : "folder" }

            <span>{elements.element}</span></div>
          <div className={elements.type}>{elements.description}{text}</div>
        </div>
      </li>;
    });
    return (
      <div id="COMPONENT-ReactFolderStructure">
        <h1>REACT Folder Structure</h1>
        <i class="material-icons">
            folder
        </i>
        <ul>{elementsRender}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I run it the HTML comes out as text and when I look into the inspector I see that the HTML is surrounded by "". I think int is due the the "" escaping it out but I do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `"` and render the "HTML" wich is actually JSX (React.Component)

Change this:

```
const text =`<h1>A heading</h1>`
...
const icon = "<i className="material-icons">folder </i>"
```

To:

```
const text = <h1>A heading</h1> 
...
const icon = <i className="material-icons">folder </i>
```

Comment: Gosh! Ive been messing around for hours on this! Thank you!